# Git Merge 2 branches using rebase

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-push

I created branch temp from master. Temp has 620 commits added to it.
When i rebase try to merge temp branch into master using rebase. I do not see all commits.

This is what i am doing

```
git checkout master
git pull --rebase origin master
git checkout temp
git rebase -s recursive -X ours master
git checkout master
git rebase temp
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 2):

Add automatic rebase to your global .gitconfig

```
git config --global branch.master.rebase true
git config --global branch.autosetuprebase=always
```

From the **temp** branch, you can type :

```
git checkout temp
git pull
git rebase master
```

At this point, Everything from **temp** branch is rebased on **master** branch. You need to merge **temp** with **master**

```
git checkout master
git merge temp
git commit -am "Everything is ok !"
git push
```

Comment: The correct command is 

"git config --global branch.autosetuprebase always"